# htaccess split unused stuff into array

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

### What I already achieved.

Let's say I have the following URL:

`www.example.com/api` -> `www.example.com/api/index.php`

I have an endpoint for everything I do (here **foo**), which would look like this:

`www.example.com/api/foo` -> `www.example.com/api/index.php?controller=foo&action=`

This URL accesses my "Foo-Controller", now I want to pass it an action to do:

`www.example.com/api/foo/bar` -> `www.example.com/api/index.php?controller=foo&action=bar`

This would call the method "bar" in the "Foo"-Controller.

### The Problem:

I want everything past the URL `www.example.com/api/foo/bar` to be given to me as an array.

Example:

`www.example.com/api/foo/bar/some/dummy/variables` -> `www.example.com/api/index.php?controller=foo&action=bar&params[]=some&params[]=dummy&params[]=variables`

### Reference (What I have)

Here is my current `.htaccess`-File:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Define Paths
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" "index.php?controller=$1&action=" [qsa]
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" "index.php?controller=$1&action=$2" [qsa]
```

This contains the first two examples, yet it is missing the third one.

Comment: There is no concept of an "array" on protocol level. So this is nothing that should get done on protocol level. This belongs into your application logic. So hand over those other parameters as a single data point and explode it inside your controller.